# Low temperature charging batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I was wondering what are the best rechargeable battery solutions for working in low temperature environments, ie. from -20 to -10 Celsius degrees. From what I have figured out, Li-ion batteries cannot be charged at temperatures lower than 0 Celsius degree. Lead acid batteries can be charged from -20, degrees but they are big, dont offer high capacity and cannot have many discharge cycles. 
I was wondering what would be the best solution here? I have heard that there are battery packs that provide heating coating that one can power up in order to heat the battery, but was not able to find any.
I would appreciate all hints and help.

Comment: Take a look at Lithium Titanate (LTO) batteries.

Comment: It seems that charging for those batteries is still allowed only at 0*C. I am however considering AGM lead acid batteries.

Comment: https://www.ev-power.eu/LTO-technology/Lithium-Titanate-Oxid-Battery-Cell-LTO-2-4V-10AH.html says: "(charging) : -15C to +45C"

Answer (score 1):

Lead acid (or gel or AGM), *but* only discharge/use 20 % of capacity to avoid freezing approaching -40 °C. i.e. go into winter with fully charged batteries.

Liquid NiCad can go to about -50 °C.

At Dome A and similar bury the primary spiral lithium batteries > 3 m to avoid winter temperatures (balmy -63 °C as opposed to below -80 °C on the surface). Run on them all winter, and  have 3 x solar panels spaces 120 °C for all day solar operation when the summer sun is out to save the batteries.